# Why does import error change to "cannot import name" on the second import?

Tags: python, importerror, python-import

Here's a mysterious python problem:

I'm developing a python package that occasionally reports import errors looking like `ImportError: cannot import name …`. The modules it cannot import generally

- are importable
- do not have any circular import issues (that I can detect).

I have been able to reproduce a similar effect with this simple example:

**`mypkg/__init__.py`**:

```
    from . import module_a
    yarg  ## cause import error
```

**`mypkg/module_a.py`**:

```
    print "imported module_a"
```

Now I will attempt to import the package twice. Notice that the error changes on the second import:

```
>>> import mypkg
Module A imported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mypkg/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    yarg
NameError: name 'yarg' is not defined
>>> import mypkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mypkg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import module_a
ImportError: cannot import name module_a
```

What gives?

**Note:**

- the problem goes away if I use an absolute import instead
- if I delete the key `sys.modules['mypkg.module_a']` after the first import, then the second import gives me back the original error message

Comment: What version of Python is this?

Comment: Well, 2.6 and lower has different behavior with regards to relative imports. You can alter it by adding `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top of the source file. But I'm not sure it makes a difference for 2.7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can illustrate *what* is causing the difference between each `import`, but I'm not expert enough on Python's import process to be able to explain the *why* very well.

```
>>> import sys
>>> before_import = set(sys.modules.keys())
>>> import mypkg
imported module_a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mypkg\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    yarg  ## cause import error
NameError: name 'yarg' is not defined
>>> after_import = set(sys.modules.keys())
>>> after_import.difference(before_import)
set(['mypkg.module_a'])
```

When you `import mypkg`, it successfully imports `module_a` and adds it to `sys.modules`. Then `mypkg` errors and *doesn't* get added itself to the `sys.modules` dictionary. Deleting the entry allows you to reimport with the same error:

```
>>> import sys
>>> del sys.modules['mypkg.module_a']
>>> import mypkg
imported module_a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mypkg\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    yarg  ## cause import error
NameError: name 'yarg' is not defined
```

Now, what I *think* is happening is:

1. `import mypkg` starts the import process for `mypkg`
2. As it's processing `mypkg`, it *successfully* imports `module_a` as
   a subpackage of itself and adds it to `sys.modules`
3. When it hits the error, the import process for `mypkg` fails and no
   entry for `mypkg` is left in `sys.modules`
4. The conjunction of the package failing but the subpackage succeeding
   conflicts with subsequent imports

That's about the best I can fathom, sorry. Python's import process is something of a black art.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that your package is failing to load. You've put some nonsense (`yarg` by itself) in the `__init__.py` file.  This means that `mypkg` can't be imported. Because of this, `mypkg.module_a` can't be imported either.

I suspect you get different errors because Python is doing some caching of the module state. The first time you try importing `mypkg` the import of its submodule `module_a` is allowed even though `mypkg` is in the process of being loaded. The second time, the fact that `mypkg` doesn't work right is cached, so `mypkg.module_a` fails to load since its parent package is broken.

Comment: I think this answer is very close, but there are some problems: 1) why would switching to absolute imports change this and 2) module_a actually _has_ imported correctly; I can access anything defined there by looking in sys.modules['mypkg.module_a'], so why would python report that it is not importable, rather than accepting that it is already imported? (I rather suspect these are questions for the python devs)